# access value based on id(Which has period in their value) attribute in jquery...!

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to access value based on id(Which has period in their value) attribute.

Example :

if suppose my radio button is

```
<form:radiobutton path="abc.def" id="abc.def" />
```

now how to access value of abc.def using jquery

I tried using

```
$('#abc.def').val()
```

but it's not working. 
diamondSingleStone.originalLotnumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `#abc.def` will look for an element whose `id` attribute is 'abc' and which also has the CLASS 'def', since `.` denotes class.

In short, don't use `.` in ID attributes - it will cause you problems for the above reason. If the code is unchangeable you will need to select it in different fashion:

```
var el = $('[id="abc.def"]');
```

Comment: if i use $('[id="abc.def"]').val() , then it's working normally.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('[id="abc.def"]').val()
```

it works here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGFuk/